# $\text{diag}(M^t,\ldots,M^t)=[\text{diag}(M,\ldots,M)]^t$ with $t$ is real and $M$ is a positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, block-matrices

Let $M$ be positive operator on a complex Hilbert space $E$.

Since the square root of a positive operator is unique, then

$$\begin{pmatrix} M^{1/2} &  \\
 & \ddots & \\
 & & M^{1/2}
 \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix} M &  \\
 & \ddots & \\
 & & M
 \end{pmatrix}^{1/2}
.$$

> Now if $t\in (0,\infty)$ be real number. Is
> $$\begin{pmatrix} M^{t} &  \\
>  & \ddots & \\
>  & & M^{t}
>  \end{pmatrix}
> =\begin{pmatrix}M &  \\
>  & \ddots & \\
>  & & M
>  \end{pmatrix}^{t}
> ?$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$, $B$ are unital $C^\ast$-algebras and $\pi\colon A\to B$ is a unital $\ast$-homomorphism, then $\pi(f(x))=f(\pi(x))$ for every normal $x\in A$ and continuous function $f$ on the spectrum of $x$. If $f$ is a polynomial in $z$ and $\bar z$, this follows easily from the properties of a unital $\ast$-homomorphism, and for general continuous $f$ one can approximate by polynomials in $z$ and $\bar z$.

Now you can apply this result to the case when $B=M_n(A)$, $\pi(x)=\mathrm{diag}(x,\dots,x)$ and $f(\lambda)=\lambda^t$.

Comment: Please what do mean by $B=M_n(A)$?

Comment: The $n\times n$ matrices whose entries are elements of $A$ (i.e. bounded linear operators on $E$ in your case).

Comment: Thank you Professor